# CSS Selector for xml:lang

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, lang

I want to use different CSS selectors for every language. I've got an HTML document like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es">
     ...
</html>
```

I have got different languages, and I want to change the style depending on the language.

I've tried `html:lang(es)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend updating the language attribute in the html aswell. You could select this element using CSS aswell. xml is an attribute that you can select with CSS.

```
html[xml:lang="es"]{ //your style }
```

You could also use change the css with the `lang` attribute

```
html[lang="es"]{ //your style }
```

```css
html[xml\:lang="es"] body{ background: red; } 
html[xml\:lang="en"] body{ background: green; }
```

```html
<html xml:lang="es" lang="es">
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to escape the colon like so: `html[xml\:lang="es"]` (There's also the fact that xml:lang is an XML-based attribute but that's not a rabbit hole I want to go down. All that matters here as far as HTML is concerned is escaping the colon.)

Comment: I updated my answer using a \ tag. But I'll still recommend placing the language attribute on the html tag as a `lang` tag.

Answer (score 3):

The `xml:lang` attribute will only be effective when the XHTML is interpreted as XML. When it is being parsed as HTML, you need to use the `lang` attribute.

You can test this by saving your XHTML document locally with a XML file extension and then loading in the browser, and the current CSS selector should work.

**If you can control the generation of the XHTML, the easiest thing to do is to use both of the language attributes, to ensure that it is evaluated properly when read as either XML or HTML.**

This is described in the W3C international [Declaring language in HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations) page:

> When serving XHTML 1.x or polyglot pages as text/html, use both the lang attribute and the xml:lang attribute together every time you want to set the language. The xml:lang attribute is the standard way to identify language information in XML. Ensure that the values for both attributes are identical.

```
<html lang="fr" xml:lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

> The xml:lang attribute is not actually useful for handling the file as HTML, but takes over from the lang attribute any time you process or serve the document as XML. The lang attribute is allowed by the syntax of XHTML, and may also be recognized by browsers. When using other XML parsers, however (such as the lang() function in XSLT) you can't rely on the lang attribute being recognized.

Comment: Yes. Don't replace the :lang() pseudo with an attribute selector just to make your CSS work with poorly written markup. Write your markup correctly in the first place so your CSS will actually work as intended. Although, for the sake of simplicity I'd recommend just leaving out the xmlns and xml:lang attributes altogether - most people will never ever serve their documents as application/xhtml+xml in the first place, rendering the xmlns and xml:lang attributes nothing but a waste of bandwidth.